# Attach the Complete button to new tasks in a to do list app

Tags: javascript

I tried to build a to do list app. My code doesn't attach the Complete button to the new tasks.

edit: After changing the code, I realized I'd like to store it in the LocalStorage, but I can't figure out a way how.

```js
var addBtn = document.getElementById("addButton");
var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
var mainList =  document.getElementById("mainList");

function addCompleteBtn (newTask){
  let completeBtn = document.createElement("button");
  completeBtn.className="btn btn-success";
  completeBtn.id="completeBtn"
  completeBtn.textContent="Completed";
  newTask.appendChild(completeBtn);
};

addBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  var newTask = document.createElement("li");
  if(textInput.value === ""){
    alert("Please enter a task");
 }else{       
      newTask.textContent=textInput.value
      newTask.className="task d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item bg-primary mt-2";
      addCompleteBtn(newTask);
      mainList.appendChild(newTask);
      textInput.value="";   
    }
});
mainList.addEventListener("click",(evt)=>{
    if (evt.target.id==="completeBtn") {
       let listItem = evt.target.parentNode
       let mainUl = listItem.parentNode
       mainUl.removeChild(listItem);
 }
});
```

Comment: Please post your code as text. Most people do not want to click a link to view your code.

Comment: You need to include the actual code in the question. Please don't try to bypass the demo link issue by turning it into a code block. Demos are great but only as support for what actually exists in the question. See [ask]. Also a good thing to learn right away is how to check for errors in browser developer tools console (F12) and report those errors when you ask questions. Very often you can paste the error message into a web search and find potential reasons for that error

Comment: It's `document.createElement` not `document.createItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `document.createElement` not `createItem`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was blind, and sorry to all for my mistakes, I am new to the forum.